# R For Loop Output Into Table

Tags: r, function, loops, rstudio

Here is a snipit of my code:

```
parameters$x<-0
parameters$y<-0
for (x in c(1:2)){
  for (y in c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,100)){
control <- rpart.control(minsplit = x,
                         minbucket = round(y),
                         maxdepth = 10,
                         cp = 0)
tune_fit <- rpart(survived~., data = data_train, method = 'class', control = control)

parameters[x] <-accuracy_tune(tune_fit)
}}
```

I basically want a table that has the `x` rows and `y` columns (based on what my `x` and `y` inputs are in the for loop) and then storing the output of the function as a value in this new table. I recognize what I am trying to do with parameters is not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide [example data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) in order to make your issue reproducible!

Comment: *is not working* ... is not helpful for us. Please post errors or undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

With this solution, whatever result `accuracy_tune` returns will get stored in the matrix. Although, you haven't provided much information, but here's my solution:

```
# create matrix to store output
parameters <- matrix(data=NA, nrows=2, ncols=10)

# value to use for iteration
x_vals <- c(1:2))
y_vals <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,100))

# iterate over values
for (x in seq(x_vals){
  for (y in seq(y_vals){
control <- rpart.control(minsplit = x,
                         minbucket = round(y),
                         maxdepth = 10,
                         cp = 0)
tune_fit <- rpart(survived~., data = data_train, method = 'class', control = control)

parameters[x,y] <-accuracy_tune(tune_fit)
}}

# set row and column names
colnames(parameters) <- y_vals
row.names(parameters) <- x_vals
```